# Sum of Row and Column . Sum of row is done but when do sum of column then is show sum of column same every textboxes

Tags: textbox, sum, row, multiple-columns, html.textboxfor

```
  foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
    {
        <tr id="tmsData">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>@itm.TaskName</td>

            @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)

              {

                <td > <input class="txtTaskHours date@(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyyy"))" style="width:50px;"   type="number" id="@(itm.ID.ToString() + ':' + Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyyy"))" /></td>
            }
            <td><strong><input class="JKL" style="width:50px" /></strong></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>


           </tr>
    }

 }

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {

            <td ><strong><input class="JKLL " id="Tue" style="width:50px" /></strong></td>

        }
        <td></td><script> 

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $(".txtTaskHours").on('keyup change', calculateSum);
                });

                function calculateSum() {
                    var $input = $(this);
                    var $row = $input.closest('tr');
                    var sum = 0;

                    $row.find(".txtTaskHours").each(function () {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
                    });

                    $row.find(".JKL").val(sum.toFixed(2));

                    //adding column values 

                    var eid = ($input.attr('id'));

                    var arrTaskTextBoxes = $('.date' + eid.substr(eid.indexOf(":") + 1, 8));
                    var sum = 0.00  

                    for (var i = 0; i < arrTaskTextBoxes.length; i++) {
                        if (arrTaskTextBoxes[i].value != '') {
                           sum+= parseFloat(arrTaskTextBoxes[i].value) || 0;
                        }

                    }
                    $(".JKLL").val(sum.toFixed(2));


                   //document.getElementById('Tue').value = sum.toFixed(2);
                    console.log(sum);

                }
```

This is my script code i tried this but when sum of column is take 
   place then if we fill data in top to bottom then its show sum in whole of the 
   `textbox`. Row sum is done very properly way but sum of the column issue is 
   coming sum of column show is correct but is sow all the text boxes that is 
   give in the bottom row. I use this script method here i am using eid by which 
   id of every textbox we take.